# How do I get to know the columns of a combined cell?

Tags: excel, vba

A moment ago someone asked me if we can use a combined column as a reference point, I did not know what to answer, for them I am here.

The idea was this:

[image]

So when you select the combined cell A, you could get the columns of that combined cell.

¿For what? Well, when a new column is added, this new column will be added to the merge cell, so when we use VBA we get the columns of that segment, because the intention is not to depend on "Range (" A1: A5 ")" so static, and well be able to select that range of columns even if new columns are added where the combined cell is located.

Because our intention is that the combined cells function as segments, where we only need the combined columns and this can be dynamic.

If anyone knows a better way to do this, then welcome .

Comment: why doesn't it make sense? @braX

Comment: You can identify start column and end column of merged cells as per this reference <https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/merged-cell-start-end-columns/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the start and end of a merged range with two user-defined functions.  One user-defined functions determines the starting cell of the merged range and the other determines the ending cell in the merged range.

This is an example of how to use the UDFs in formulas.

- The merged range is D16:E16.
- Cell D6 is the UDF for the merged range's starting column number.  `MergedCellColumnStart(D14)`
- Cell D7 is the UDF for the merged range's ending column number. `MergedCellColumnEnd(D14)`
- Cell D4 uses the results of D6 and D7 to build the address range of the merged cells. `ADDRESS(ROW(D$16),D6)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(D$16),D7)`
- The respective formulas for each are also shown in cells E4, E6 and E7.

[image]

```
Private Function MergedCellColumnStart(MergedCell As Range) As Integer

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range

        Set rng = MergedCell
        Set rng = rng.MergeArea
        Set rngStart = rng.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rngEnd = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

        MergedCellColumnStart = rngStart.Column


End Function

Private Function MergedCellColumnEnd(MergedCell As Range) As Integer

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range

        Set rng = MergedCell
        Set rng = rng.MergeArea
        Set rngStart = rng.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rngEnd = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

        MergedCellColumnEnd = rngEnd.Column

End Function
```